# Tooltip in table with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table with td `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis`
I want to make a tooltip, that will "stick" **EDIT: to the text (not outside the td box)**  but I cannot do it with `overflow: hidden`. The tooltip is cutted off or not even visible.

I tried to find a solution for my problem but sadly couldn't find good one.

This is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/480cgv0j/1/

Maybe some JS will help here? But I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: what is fix for this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

Without changing the tooltip system to a javascript body appended tooltip, the best approach is this:

https://jsfiddle.net/480cgv0j/6/

The changes are:

```
 .tooltip:hover { overflow: visible; }
```

Change the classname `tooltip` from `<a>` element to `<td>` element:

**Before:**

```
 <td><a href="#" class="tooltip">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<span class="tooltiptext">you won't see me</span></a></td>
```

**Now:**

```
 <td class="tooltip"><a href="#">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<span class="tooltiptext">you won't see me</span></a></td>
```

Comment: well it doesn't work well for me, because it produces slider [link](http://i.imgur.com/9kzt6TH.png)

Comment: See the edition with `overflow: visible`. It doesn't work perfect, but it works. To make it work perfect you need a javascript tooltip that will append to `<body>` and the position will be calculated based on the element position.